# Start coding in Java with NetBeans

Tags: java

There is a lot of information about Java around, but I don't understand how to setup everything.

I have a Mac. I heard the JDK comes with Macs. But is it the latest? How do I check that? Is it the J2SE or J2EE?

I want to create a web app. I installed NetBeans. When I choose create project there is a list of Java options. There is Java/Java EE/Java FX/Java Web. Which one should i choose? and afterwards, what is what? What is War?

I want to find a good tutorial/ebook explaining all these Java terms and how to setup Java/Java Server(Glassfish/Tomcat) on a Mac and with NetBeans to code a web app? A good one!

Comment: Aarrggh, caps everywhere! Caps hurt me eyes!

Comment: For future reference: you should use capitals when you begin a sentence, and when you use the first person pronoun **I**, even in the middle of a sentence. Do not use capitals as a form of emphasis. For that use italics or bold. Just add some asterisks around the words: `*italic*` = *italic*, `**bold**` = **bold**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The netbeans tutorials can be found here:  http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/java-se.html

To start off, just make a plain Java project.  The other types all probably include different plugins or libraries that you won't need right away. A WAR is an archive of Java classes and other files that constitutes a web application.

The default version of the JDK that you have on your Mac should be fine, but if you want to upgrade or mess around with any other Java preferences, OS X offers all that for you.  Apple has a good tutorial here:  http://developer.apple.com/java/faq/

**Edit**:  Ok, if you want to make a web app then the first step is to learn how a Java web app is organized.  That will make your life much easier.  Java EE is mostly a buzzword (IMO) and it refers to a specific set of libraries.  It's not important to know what's officially considered Java EE and what isn't.  To learn about what a Java web app looks like, the best place is the Tomcat manual.  Read [this section](https://sec1.woopra.com/docs/appdev/index.html), then make a WAR project in Netbeans and you should have a good start.  Don't try to bite off too much at first, just make a Hello, World! app.

Comment: but i wanna make a web app. shouldnt i create a JEE project?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to go straight into Java Enterprise Development is going to be too steep a learning curve unless you already know Java.  Take a step back, and start going through some [Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/).

It will likely be a while before you can tackle Java EE (it can be a monster).

Comment: so easy to start with php. just install MAMP. why i know if i could have a good tutorial explaining what war and jar files are, what source packages are and so on, it would not be a monster to learn it. afterall, without information everyone is a lost child. with good information, you know the system after 1 day. i know php, learning the syntax for java is not difficult part. the difficult part is understanding where to do what and what is what in the "java system" havent found any good explanation yet how i start coding with netbeans with JEE:( what a shame.

Comment: Why are you so worried about JEE?  Do you know what it is, and have you decided you need it based on that?

Comment: according to some answers of my prior posts here in SO i will need to use J2EE to code web apps in Java and that is all i know:)

Answer (score 1):

An excellent resource for learning Java development is [Java Passion](http://javapassion.com/).

There you can learn basic Java development, and the [Java EE tutorials](http://www.javapassion.com/j2ee/) will also get you started developing web applications.

Here are some links on how to setup Tomcat / Glassfish for Mac OS X.

- [Tomcat on OS X](http://developer.apple.com/internet/java/tomcat1.html)
- [Glassfish on OS X](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/pelegri/archive/2005/11/running_glassfi.html)